# Building HTML passing it in as XML and also using javascript?

Tags: javascript

This project I'm working on is building large amounts of HTML into a string and then putting it an XML string.

Then once that XML is fully built it is being saved into a hidden input form element.  Then it is being passed to a javascript function which then parses that xml string.

The javascript function applies the `$.parseXML` to the value that was in the hidden input variable.

For the most part everything is working, however, there are also some javascript calls in that HTML string (i.e onclick).

When I look at the HTML string in Firebug the onclick event looks like this:

```
onclick="lbRowClick(this,ptObj_listbox0, 0);"
```

The problem I am having is right now the lbRowClick function is never firing.  I imagine that I will also have an issue with the second parameter not having quotes around it as well (every time I put quotes around it I get an XML error).

I've been looking at this for awhile and I'm not sure which way to go.  Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I imagine that I will also have an issue with the second parameter not having quotes around it as well (every time I put quotes around it I get an XML error).

If the `onclick` block has a syntax error in it, it won't execute and `lbRowClick` won't be called. If the 2nd parameter should be a string, try using single-quotes:

```
onclick="lbRowClick(this, 'ptObj_listbox0', 0);"
```

If that results in an XML error, try using `&#39;` for them:

```
onclick="lbRowClick(this, &#39;ptObj_listbox0&#39;, 0);"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, you might try using **[`Live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)**, and see if it will pick up the late bindings in the HTML string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115864/whats-wrong-with-the-jquery-live-method live is deprecated. (cleaning up old posts :P i'm sure you already know this) and even though it exists should not be used. jQuery team suggests delegate() over live()